# How to find Object inside array in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

This is how the database looks like

```
[
//document1
    {
        "email": "raj@gmail.com",
        "cart": [
            {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "Pen",
            }
        ]
    },
//document2
    {
        "email": "vishal21@gmail.com",
        "cart": [
            {
                "id": 42,
                "name": "Ball",
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

How to write mongoose query to find the Item inside cart in a particular document using Email.
For example, I need the item with id 4 which is in the cart of the document with the email "raj@gmail.com"

1. find a document with email "raj@gmail.com"
2. Inside the document in the cart array find the item with id "4"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try running this query

```
  db.collection.find({
  email: "raj@gmail.com",
  cart: {
    $elemMatch: {
      id: 4
    }
  }
})
```

I have first queried it using the email address. Then in the array I have used `elemMatch` for `obj` to match `id`